# How do I format a binary output the same way as the input after bitwise XOR?

Tags: python, binary, checksum, xor

I'm trying to do a bitwise XOR on two binary numbers like the following:

```
a_telegram = "$00;02;A1;00000000;*"
checksum = "00000000"

testt="{0:08b}".format(int(hex(ord(a_telegram[2])),16))
result = int(testt) ^ int(checksum)

print (checksum)
print (testt)
print (result)
```

Which outputs

```
00000000
00110000
110000
```

Why is the result not in 8, but in 6 bits? I guess it's a formatting problem but I don't see what I have to change.
(Please excuse my bad english, I'm not a native english speaker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
a_telegram = "$00;02;A1;00000000;*"
checksum = "00000000"

testt="{0:08b}".format(int(hex(ord(a_telegram[2])),16))
result = int(testt) ^ int(checksum)

print (checksum)
print (testt)
print (f'{result:08}')
```

outs

```
00000000
00110000
00110000
>>>
```